# If the app crashes once, I cannot start the app unless I restart my Android phone

Tags: android, logcat, android-debug

I am developing an app for Android on my HTC Desire HD; at times during the App development the app crashes due to some reason or the other.

But once it crashes, it won't start in any case and the only solution is to restart my device.

- I have tried to run it again using Ctrl+f11
- I have even tried uninstalling the app from the device uninstaller.
- Even uninstalled it using `adb uninstall 'com.example.www'` with a successful uninstallation.

It does not show any kind of log messages in `logcat`, just that `killProcess, pid=xxxx`

Can you please provide a solution to this; as my device takes 5 mins to reboot and as the app gets complicated, its crashes even more.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can see all running processes which you can debug in DDMS perspective in Eclipse:[image]

Check if your application is runing,if it is you can stop it by clicking the stop button near the screenshot one.
Or you can use the process id to kill the process in the shell if you have a SU rights:

```
adb shell
su
pkill #pid
```